# Modular inverse of a function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

If $f$ is a function defined by $f(x) = (7x + 2)\; mod\; 12$, then what is its inverse? I tried starting with a Euclidean algorithm but got halfway through.

Comment: FWIW, you _could_ use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find the multiplicative inverse of 7 mod 12 by solving $7r - 12k = 1$. However, there are only 4 numbers in the reduced residue set mod 12: $\{1,5,7,11\}$ so it's easy enough just to check all 4 possibilities. In fact, each number in that set is its own reciprocal mod 12.

Comment: More simply, mod $\,6\!:\ 7^{-1}\equiv 1^{-1}\equiv 1,\,$ so mod $12\!:$ $\,7^{-1}\equiv 1$ or $1+6,\,$ But it's not $1$  so $\ldots$

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the function $f(x)=(ax+b)\mathrm{mod}\,m$ is invertible iff $a$ is invertible modulo $m$, that is iff $\gcd(a,m)=1$. In this case, the inverse is 
$$
f^{-1}(x)=a^{-1}(x-b)\mathrm{mod}\,m
$$
in your example $a=7$, $b=2$, $m=12$. Note that indeed $\gcd(12,7)=1$ and 
$7\cdot7=1\mathrm{mod}\,12$ so 
$$
f^{-1}(x)=7(x-2)\mathrm{mod}\,12=(7x-2)\mathrm{mod}\,12
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$7x+2 \equiv y \mod 12$$

$$7x \equiv y-2 \mod 12$$

$$49x \equiv 7(y-2) \mod 12$$

$$x \equiv 7(y-2) \mod 12$$

Note that $49=4(12)+1$